# How to Install mlr3extralearners in R?

Tags: r, github, package, survival, mlr3

So I am going to do some survivalsvm process and I need the mlr3extralearners package from GitHub. When I tried to install it locally using the tar.gz file, it said

```
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages: installation of package  had non-zero exit status
```

I also tried to use the zip file, and it said

```
install.packages("C:/Users/Ivan/Downloads/mlr3extralearners-0.5.49.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary", lib="C:/R-4.2.1/library")
```

then nothing happened.

I also tried using `devtools::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3extralearners")`, but the output was the same when I used the tar.gz file. When I checked in my library, I already have the mlr3extralearners package, but when I call it using `library(mlr3extralearners)`, it does not work. Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide error message when you run `library(mlr3extralearners)`?

Comment: is not a valid installed package

Comment: What's the full error message you're getting when trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

https://rdrr.io/github/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners/

I believe this should work for you:
Install the latest version of this package by entering the following in R:

```r
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("mlr-org/mlr3extralearners")
```